# How can I solve this PDE with initial conditions?

Tags: differential-equations

I wish to solve the following second order partial differential equation

$$u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$$

with the initial conditions

$$u(x,0)=e^x,\quad  u_t(x,0)=\sin x$$

In *Mathematica*, I evaluated the following code:

```
DSolve[{D[p[x, t], {t, 2}] == c^2 *(D[p[x, t], {x, 2}]), 
        p[x, 0] == Exp[x], D[p[x, t], t] == Sin[x]},
      p[x, t], {x, t}]
```

*Mathematica* responded with

> DSolve::deqx: Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions.

I think the problem lies in the initial conditions. How can I fix this code?

Comment: Hi Scorpio19891119! Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I formatted your post for more convenient to read. Please do check the source code to see how I did it by click the [**time** above my avatar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/18083/revisions) at the left bottom. Additionally please refer to [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for more detail.

Comment: You should use `Derivative[0, 1][p][x, 0] == Sin[x]` instead of `D[p[x, t], t] == Sin[x]` in your code. (Although this correction did not seem to be sufficient to give a solution.)

Comment: @Silvia That notation doesn't really matter (OK, one has to add `/.t->0` in his approach, but it's not the main problem). I feel tempted to answer, but it looks a lot like a homework problem. As a hint: first solve without the initial conditions, leading to two functions `C[1]` and `C[2]`. *Then* find those functions by imposing the initial conditions at `t = 0`. This can be done by converting *both* conditions to a set of equations only involving `C'[i]` at `x` and `-x`.

Comment: @Jens +1 btw I'm aware of the standard method for dealing with so-called traveling wave solutions, but wondering why `DSolve` can't handle this..

Comment: @Silvia That's a valid question - but for now the only answer seems to be: it just can't be done. At least looking at the [DSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html) documentation, it states that the acceptable form for PDEs is *only* `DSolve[eqn, y, {x1, x2, ...}]` and not `DSolve[{eqn1, eqn2 ...}, y, {x1, x2, ...}]` with multiple equations as would be the use case here.

Comment: The problem is not well posed. You gave the initial conditions, but you didn't give the boundary conditions (including a possible implicit condition at t = infinity). I think Mathematica needs all boundaries defined with Dirichlet, Neuman or Robin conditions. Cauchy conditions are questionable.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DSolve.html) documentation, it states that the acceptable form for partial differential equations is only `DSolve[eqn, y, {x1, x2, ...}]` and not `DSolve[{eqn1, eqn2 ...}, y, {x1, x2, ...}]` with multiple equations as would be the use case here.

The documentation may in fact not be quite consistent here: there is an example of an "initial condition" in a first-order PDE on [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/SolveAPartialDifferentialEquation.html), but the wording of the docs indicates that there's no guarantee that `DSolve` can handle arbitrary PDEs with initial or boundary conditions. That makes sense because most such PDEs have no closed-form  solutions.

So you have to solve the PDE without the initial conditions first. That will give you a well-known result but in terms of functions named in *Mathematica*'s standard way, `C[1]` and `C[2]`. Then you'll need to figure out a way to determine these unknown functions from the initial conditions. Since I don't know if this is a homework problem, I'll leave it at that for now.

Another approach would be to use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NDSolve.html), which *does* allow you to specify initial conditions (see under "Applications", "Partial Differential Equations").

Comment: +1 Indeed! Never noticed that statement before.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to post a `LaplaceTransform`-based solution:

```
eqn = D[p[x, t], {t, 2}] == c^2*(D[p[x, t], {x, 2}]);
ic = {p[x, 0] == Exp[x], D[p[x, t], t] == Sin[x] /. t -> 0};

teqn = LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s] /. Rule @@@ ic

(* Notice that p[x, t] in the following equation implies the Laplace transform of p[x, t] *)
tsol = DSolve[teqn /. HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, t, s] :> a, p[x, t], x]

sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol[[1, 1, 2]], s, t] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> E^x Cosh[c t] + C[2] DiracDelta[t - x/c] + C[1] DiracDelta[t + x/c] + (Sin[c t] Sin[x])/c
> ```

Since OP doesn't mention anything about `x`, I'll leave those constants there.

---

I've wrap the above procedure into a function `pdeSolveWithLaplaceTransform` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84297/1871) and now the problem can be solved like:

```
pdeSolveWithLaplaceTransform[eqn, ic, p[x, t], t, x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `D[p[x, t], t] == Sin[x]` in the OP's code with `(D[p[x, t], t]/.x->0) == Sin[x]` in Mathematica 10.3 gives me

> {{p[x,t]->1/2 (E^(-Sqrt[c^2] t+x)+E^(Sqrt[c^2] t+x))+(Sin[Sqrt[c^2] t] Sin[x])/Sqrt[c^2]}}