# Solving an unusual PDE

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I have a PDE in the form

$$\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + 3*\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y} - 4*\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right)f(x,y) = xy; \quad f(x,0) = \sin(x); \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)|_{y=x}   = 0$$

How can I solve this and plot the solution?

Comment: Where do all the derivatives act?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, so you saw what I meant. Thanks for fixing the post :)

Comment: no probs :) cheers

Comment: A follow-up: from the way you have written the question am I right to assume that there is no freedom for the $x$-dependence? Because you wrote $f(x,y)=\sin x$ are we to assume that we need to find only the $y$-dependence of the function?

Comment: I believe so , yes

Comment: _How can I solve this_ I must be overlooking something. Solve for what? You already says solution is $f(x,y)=\sin x$?

Comment: That is the initial condition, sorry#

Comment: Initial conditions? I see no time $t$ anywhere in the PDE?

Comment: okay--let's ignore that. How can I solve for the general solution? I the sin(x) is simply just an initial function. f(x,0)

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve this analytically. So you need to try numerical solution. But to see the issue, you can start by solving it analytically without the condition

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)|_{y=x}   = 0
$$

Then after solving it, make an equation to solve the constant of integration $c_1$. In this case, since this is a PDE and not ODE, the constant of integration is an arbitrary function $c_1$. This makes it not possible to solve for it:

```
ClearAll[f, x, y];
pde = D[f[x, y], {x, 2}] + 3*D[D[f[x, y], x], y] - 4*D[f[x, y], {y, 2}] == x*y
bc = f[x, 0] == Sin[x]
sol = DSolveValue[{pde, bc}, f[x, y], {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now apply the second "condition"

```
der = D[sol, x] /. y -> x
eq = der == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now if you can solve for this arbitrary function $c_1$ from the above equation, then you have solved the PDE.

But it is not possible to solve for $c_1$ above. But may be someone can find a trick to do it. Notice that $c_1$ is actually a function of $x,y$ by looking at the solution above.

Comment: Perhaps an interesting comment: the Laplace transformation suggested by [`xzczd`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84171/analytic-solution-of-dynamic-euler-bernoulli-beam-equation-with-compatibility-co/84297#84297) fails to do it as well - assuming I did not do anything stupid with said code